# Swift 4 Scrollview Constraints Issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, constraints

I added a scrollview to my viewController and anchored it to my view, like this:

```
class MainContainer: UIViewController {

    let mainScrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        scrollView.bounces = false
        scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        return scrollView
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        view.addSubview(mainScrollView)


        mainScrollView.anchor(top: view.topAnchor, left: view.leftAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, right: view.rightAnchor, topConstant: 0, leftConstant: 0, bottomConstant: 0, rightConstant: 0, widthConstant: 0, heightConstant: 0)

    }
}
```

The above code works great. Constraints work as expected 
I then try to append a view to it by adding

`mainScrollView.addSubview(cameraView.view)`

That is when the constraints act weird on my scrollview. For some reason the width and height of the scrollview is doubled. Here is a screenshot of my view hierarchy to illustrate my issue

[image]

In the image I selected the scrollview and right clicked to "Show Constraints" which for some reason are doubled in width and height. Before adding the view controller the constraints where fine. The added view controller appears fine but the constraints on the scrollview are messed.

Comment: Scrollview.translateauto.... = false

Comment: Thanks for the answer, did not work though. The constraints are still odd @HenShabat

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that **cameraView.view**'s top , bottom , leading and trailing constraints are hooked to the scrollview (the superview) then give a height and width to cameraView.view , also don't forget to make **translateAutoresizing**.... equal to false for the **scrollvie**w . . .